# What's good word to indicate addition, deletion and updation of employee data?

Tags: single-word-requests

We are creating a section in the our software that shows all added, deleted and updated( personal details updated). I am not able to think of word for this. Should "Changes" work?

Comment: Note that *updation* in your title is not English. *Updating* is a noun form for *update*.

Comment: I think this is usually referred to as an "audit" of the changes.

Comment: The actual list of changes made may be called the "audit log" or "audit trail".

Comment: "Audit" seems more like history (or logs). It's not a log, it's the place where they need to take actions to process all additions and deletions.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Please make the question as presented clearer. As it stands, "shows all added/deleted/updated" is *past tense* and indicates a log of what has happened. **You** know what you're talking about: please make it clear to everyone else!

Answer (score -1):

I would refer to this as **Data Maintenance**.
Here is a link to one [definition](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/data-maintenance) of this term courtesy of Law Insider.

Comment: Maintenance in this sense is what you do to a database to ensure it accurately reflects reality.  I don’t maintain my name, I change it. And my changing it forces you to do some data maintenance on your database.  If OP’s software allows users to change their name and then allows an admin to get a list of all changes, I would not refer to that list as a list of data maintenance activities. But if a database was stale and I had a list of changes that would make the database current I might say that it was a list of updates and the action of applying those updates was a data maintenance action.